# How to set redirectURI within a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a VB.Net WinForms app that uses Google GMail service for sending e-mail on behalf of the user, pulling the users default signature data to add to the e-mail.  Trying to find end-to-end examples of common scenarios seems to be an impossibility.

Anyways ...

After authenticating the user for my application, I call a routine to authorize the application to use some Google Services:

```
   Private Async Function DoAuthenticationAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim secrets As ClientSecrets

    'this obtains the application secrets data
    Using strm As New System.IO.FileStream("client_secret.json", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(strm).Secrets
    End Using

    Try
        'this is the magic black box that does the authorizing.
        Common.credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, Common.googleScopes,
                                                             "user", CancellationToken.None,
                                                             New FileDataStore("Google", False))

        Dim init As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        init.HttpClientInitializer = Common.credential

        Dim svc = New GmailService(init)

        'this grabs the list of all e-mail aliases for the signed-in user and selects the primary
        Dim result = svc.Users.Settings.SendAs.List("me").Execute

        For Each itm In result.SendAs
            If itm.IsPrimary.HasValue Then
                If itm.IsPrimary Then
                    'save as the signature blob to use.
                    Common.mySignature = itm.Signature
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

I have been fighting with this for over a week.  After calling this code, the application is hanging immediately after authorizing the the user permissions and persisting those permissions to the FileDataStore.  The app is completely unresponsive and cannot accept focus.  However the credentials have been persisted.

If I kill the app in Task Manager, restart the app, everything works fine going forward.

I am making an educated guess this is related to the redirectURI used heavily in any non-Google API Client  for .Net samples.  I cannot find any way to set this using the Google API Client for .Net.

If anyone can point me to a resource that provides real-world end-to-end samples of how to use this in .Net (C# or VB.Net) in WinForms it would be greatly appreciated.  If I can get this worked out, I will create my own end-to-end sample and post it.

Comment: Okay hang in there might take a minute to debug this.  First question Does it open the web browser for the consent screen?  If so is there a file with the consent in %appData% ?   is this old pre .net core win forms or the new .net 6 win forms?

Comment: The method take 6 parameters and you only have 5.  Where is the datastore?  See : https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Auth/latest/api/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: Yes the web browser opens up and asks which account to use.  Then user is advised which permissions it is asking the user to authorize.  When you authorize, it goes to a blank page telling you to go back to your application ... which is now hung.

Comment: jdweng - Thank you for the response.  I did not notice this parameter initially.  It was not used in the example I initially found (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)  It is optional.  I also cannot find a useful description what this parameter does and how it is used.

Comment: It seems I may have found my own solution.  I may have been using async methods wrong and my app was waltzing ahead before a method was completing ... leaving the app in a weird state.  I created a new async Run method which calls a DoAuthorizeAsync method which does little more than process the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync call. The Run method then calls a routine which creates a GMail service to get the remaining data.  This seems to work in my main app and a simple demo I created.